# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, opencart2.x

I recently updated my module to open cart **2.x** from **1.5**. I was using webservice in my module and it was working fine in 1.5 version. But when i updated to 2.x iam getting this error.

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from** 'https://abc.xyz.com/EndiciaParamWebService?wsdl' : **Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

I am calling my soap client like this.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient("http://hxlabelserver-heurixtics.rhcloud.com/EndiciaParamWebService?wsdl");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i am too late to answer this...but still add here so that someone can take help of it.

I also had this issue and i was left with two options:
1>openSSL was off
2>PHP version got mismatched

openssl was on for me...so then started playing with different version of php

And got it solved when reached php version 5.6

So i suggest you also can try with different version and could possibly match the good php version for your solution.

Comment: Sad to know that someone down voted it..i genuinely solved this way..and it took me around 3 hrs to solve it...